# SQL query to make CASE column

Tags: mysql

I have a data base with these tables:

```
languages: id, name
countries: id, name
country_languages: id, country_id, language_id
```

I need a query which gives me a table with the following fields:

```
language_id
language_name
active
```

**All languages** should come into the results. However if this language is spoken in country `id=39` then `active` column should be true otherwise it should be false.
Is there any straight forward to make such query in `mysql`?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match `langauges` with the mapping table using a `left outer join`, then inspect the mapping table's `id` column to see if you have a match (`active = 1`) or not (`active = 0`).

```
select distinct
    l.id
    , l.name
    , case when cl.id is null then 0 else 1 end as active
from languages l left outer join country_languages cl
    on l.id = cl.language_id
where cl.id = 39
```

Comment: I would consider making it `sum(case when cl.id is null then 0 else 1 end)` and doing `group by l.id, l.name` so languages only appear the once

Comment: @StephLocke, using both sum and group helped.